# My main form is closing by itself after 15 seconds (Visual Basic)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Everytime I execute my program, the main form closes by itself after about 15 seconds. The code is not the problem because it does the same thing when I put the whole code in comments. It's also not a key problem because it closes by itself even when I don't touch a single key when it's running. How can I fix it?

Comment: Have you tried running it under a debugger and seeing if any exceptions are causing it to close?

Comment: Everything is working fine when I start it with debugging but the second I start it without debugging, it does the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

Do you use Avast antivirus? I was getting *exactly* the same problems with VS2010 (although I my project is a c++ application rather than VS). I notice the date of your post is around the 10 March which is when it started happening to mine.

I've just worked out that Avast was auto-sandboxing my exe file and terminating it after 15 seconds, that might be what was happening to yours too.

I just added the .exe to the list of exceptions in Avast and it completely fixed the problem.